# WebRTC send custom byte audio/video data

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hello I'm trying to send custom audio data to webrtc track. In the old API I could use ScriptProcessorNode to get access to the streaming audio data via an onaudioprocessevent. The event exposes the channel data that you'll build your buffer with. But I see that in new API ScriptProcessorNode is not even creating by WebRTC.

How can I send custom byte audio or video data to webrtc stream? What classes should I stub and what methods override to make it?

Here is the code I'm trying to send to onaudioprocessevent:

```
    MediaStreamAudioSourceNode.prototype._ondataavailable = function (data) {
    console.log("node _ondataavailable connections", this._connections);
    var evt = new window.Event('audioprocess')
    evt.inputBuffer = this._context.createBuffer(this._track._meta.channelCount, data.length, this._track._meta.sampleRate)
    evt.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(data)

    for (var i in this._connections) {
      var connection = this._connections[i]
      console.log("connection is  ", connection);

      console.log("try to use onaudioprocess ", connection.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess);
      connection.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess && connection.scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess(evt)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please separate your concerns. 1) Are you able to locally play a *ScriptProcessorNode*-produced audio track? 2) Are you able to send other web audio tracks over *RTCPeerConnection*? Unless the answers are yes and yes, then I would pose those first. Also, the code you show doesn't seem to have enough context. What is a `connection`?

Comment: Also what is "old API" and "new API" referring to? Are you using some library?

Comment: old and new API of WebRTC and audio classes, which is built into the browser.
I'm trying to update this shim to make it work - https://github.com/common-tater/wkwebview-getusermedia-shim